# Ionic Storage and variables

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm a first-time student of the Ionic platform, and obviously I have some trouble with a little piece of my first application. I want to have a simple counter in a button: when this button is clicked, the counter increments by 1. Then I save the value using the Storage and I retrieve the same value in another page with "storage.get".

This is the code:

```
constructor(public storage:Storage, public platform: Platform){
  this.storage = storage;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log("I'm alive!");
    this.counter = this.storage.get("Count").then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    });
  }

  public counter = 0;

  count(){
      this.counter+=1;
      this.storage.set("Count",this.counter);
  }
```

When I re-open the app, I try to use the stored value to continue to increment the counter, but it starts again from 0: how can I increment the variable of the counter using the stored value?

Thank for your support!

Comment: When you get the value of Count, you're only logging it to the console.  Have you tried setting the value of counter .... "this.counter = data;" inside the then function?  Instead of console.log(data).

Comment: Sorry, I've pasted the wrong code: yes, I've tried to write "this.counter = data", but when I test the application with "ionic serve" it shows this error: ""Type promise<void> is not assignable to type 'number' "

Comment: Ok, I've found my error: now it works. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting this.counter to the promise call.

Do this instead:

```
this.storage.get("Count").then((data)=>{
   this.counter = data;
});
```

Also, once you declare an injection a public in the constructor, you don't need to set it again inside the constructor. It, automatically, will be available with the instance of the class. Basically, you don't need this.

```
this.storage = storage;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!